# Page Number of Middle references in Multiple References not listed

Tags: natbib

When I have multiple references:

```
blah blah \cite{ref1, ref2, ref3}
```

then ref2 will not be listed on this page in my bibliography. Instead it just has

> -> pages

with no page listed if I did not cite that reference anywhere else. In the PDF text it will show up as

> [1-3]

Comment: It seems you're using a bibliography/citation style (with `biblatex`: `numeric-comp`) that will compress multiple consecutive references into a range. Switch to `style=numeric`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The workaround I used was to remove the `compress` option from `natbib`. It listed every reference, which wasn't as nice as the range, but solved the problem. I don't know how to get the best of both worlds though.

```
%\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage[numbers,sort]{natbib}
```